# Intuitive understanding of the mechanism of uniform bending moment

Tags: equilibrium, statics

So many explanations on uniform bending moment and I can't understand until now how it works. I can somehow visualise that in order to resist the **external bending moments** created by equal and opposite loads on either sides of the beam are opposed by the **internal bending moment** by tensile and compressive stresses of the cross sections of the beam.

But I don't get to see how does this external bending moment causes the beam to bend like an arc.

Here are some images which help to facilitate my point of view.

1. The image below illustrates how bending moment is applied.

[image: This image illustrates how bending moment is applied]

2. This shows how the material reacts on a section of the beam(by tensile and compressive stresses) in response to the external moment applied to reach equilibrium.

[image]

3. This shows how the section looks like after being deformed

[image]

4. This is how the beam looks like when assuming the same behaviour throughout the beam like I assumed for a section of the beam

[image]

**Incase if that didn't make sense**

Consider 10 rubber tubes stacked on top of each other resembling a section of a beam. Apply tensile stresses ranging from maximum magnitude (apply to the tube which is at the top) to zero (to the tube which is at the middle resembling the neutral axis), in the same way apply compressive stresses to the tube which is at the bottom gradually decreasing the magnitude when approaching neutral axis. What I can observe is the 10 tubes don't form an arc rather it looks like a frustum.

Comment: “*I don't get to see how does this external bending moment causes the beam to bend like an arc.*” Your diagrams show how the top elongates in tension and the bottom contracts in compression. An arc seems like the natural result. Please clarify.

Comment: @Chemomechanics See that's where I'm lacking an understanding on. When the top elongates and the bottom compresses due to tension and compression respectively I get to visualise only the figure of a shape which resembles the projection of a frustum not the arc of a circle. In other words, I don't understand how the bottom and top parts of the cross section gets arched due to these forces. Is this due to some deformations in the atomic level, like torques acting on each transverse crossection of the beam?

Comment: Yes, the atomic spacing increases at the top and decreases at the bottom. I don’t understand your question.

Comment: See https://www.sjsu.edu/people/steven.vukazich/docs/160.7.2%20Moment%20Curvature%20Pure%20Bending%20Beam%20Theory.pdf

Comment: @Chemomechanics Consider 10 rubber tubes stacked on top of each other resembling a section of a beam. Apply tensile stresses ranging from maximum magnitude (apply to the tube which is at the top) to zero (to the tube which is at the middle resembling the neutral axis), in the same way apply compressive stresses to the tube which is at the bottom gradually decreasing the magnitude when approaching neutral axis. What I can observe is the 10 tubes don't form an arc rather it looks like a frustum.

Comment: In your example, there’s not a moment applied to each tube. But there is a moment applied to each (conceptual) horizontal layer of a continuum beam, causing curvature.

Comment: @Chemomechanics If you don't mind, could you explain how to visualise the bending of the beam according to continuum theorem. Thanks for replying

Comment: Look at all the shear strain energy the frustum shape has to store; the grid shape is totally distorted. This doesn’t occur with the arc shape. Nature seeks the lowest-energy configuration.